# how to insert int[] array into SQLDatabase.Query()

Tags: android, sql, database, android-database

i want to conctruct a following question:

1. `"_isREGULAR"` equals to `variable`
2. `"_id"` can't be equals to any element of `intArray`

`intArray` is regular `int[]` array,
`variable` is regular `int`

```
            cursor = db.query("TABLE",
                new String[]{"_id", "NAME", "_isREGULAR"},
                "_isREGULAR = ? AND _id != ?",
                new String[]{ -- ? -- },
                null,
                null,
                null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NOT IN condition (https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/in.php). In your case this:

```
String idsAsString = Arrays.toString(intArray); // results in something like "[1, 2, 3]"
idsAsString = idsAsString.substring(1, idsAsString.length()-1); // removes brackets, leaving "1, 2, 3"

cursor = db.query("TABLE",
   new String[]{"_id", "NAME", "_isREGULAR"},
   "_isREGULAR = ? AND _id NOT IN (?)",
   new String[]{variable, idsAsString},
   null,
   null,
   null);
```

Comment: not in condition can be helpfull here, thanks, but toString method is not working like that in Java

Comment: Sorry, you it should be Arrays.toString(intArray)

Comment: other problem is that second argument of query method need an String object, and the problem is how to place there an array

Comment: Did you try the code? The first two lines convert the array into a string.

Comment: i couldn't because compiler can't resolve substring method

Comment: now it works, but now i see that query method is not working like that because even if i set an String s = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")
and use that method like that:
cursor = db.query("TABLE",
   new String[]{"_id", "NAME", "_isREGULAR"},
   "_isREGULAR = ? AND _id NOT IN (?)",
   new String[]{variable, s},
a query is returning records with _id like 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: The query should be like new String[]{yourVariable, "1,4,5,6,7,8"}; the second var is a single string, containing your ids

Comment: sory, i made mistake, i had in program not String s = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8") but String s = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7" and it still dont work.

but let me ask you. If i make a query with arg _id NOT IN (?) and then put there string like "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" so query will be check every integer after comma or he will just check if for example "2" is not "1, 2,3, 4,5" and "3" is not "1,2,3,4,5" etc

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/in.php It will check for every int.

Comment: unfornutely, its still returning me records with _id like 1 or 2 or whatever, it's dont work

Comment: Can you please post the code as you are using it now?

Comment: Ok, so: this method:             
cursor = db.query("WORKOUT",
                    new String[]{"_id", "NAME"},
                    "_isREGULAR = ? AND _id NOT IN (?)",
                    new String[]{Integer.toString(1), "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7"},
                    null,
                    null,
                    "_id ASC");
is returning records which _id is 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. I can past there more code if u need

Comment: You can test the functionality online, I created a snippet: https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5b27679f0404ej04jijz57uy